# Calling a member function that is in all types held by std::variant?

Tags: c++, variant

I have a variable with the following type:

```
std::variant<std::monostate, first_custom_type, second_custom_type> var;
```

where both `first_custom_type` and `second_custom_type` have a function called `func()` which I want to execute after creating `var`.

Is there a way to just call `func()` without having to check what type `var` is holding (e.g., with `std::get`)?

Comment: Note that _not_ all types held by this particular `std::variant` have a member function called `func()`, because `std::monostate` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done using [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit). The only cornercase is `std::monostate`, but it can easily be avoided with `overloded` helper struct(example of whitch is in the link above)

```
struct s1{
    void func()
    {
        std::cout << "1";
    }
};
struct s2{
    void func()
    {
        std::cout << "2";
    }
};

template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

int main()
{
    std::variant<s1, s2, std::monostate> var1 = s1{};
    std::variant<s1, s2, std::monostate> var2 = s2{};
    std::variant<s1, s2, std::monostate> var3 = std::monostate{};

    auto functor = overloaded {
        [](std::monostate) {}, 
        [](auto& arg) {arg.func();}
    };

    std::visit(functor, var1); // 1
    std::visit(functor, var2); // 2
    std::visit(functor, var3); // nothing
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to demonstrate how to use it in this particular case? I'm looking into the documentation now (never used this before)

Comment: @David updated post to answer your question